# Disable Autoplay Windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, windows-registry, autoplay

I disabled auto play in Control Panel > AutoPlay, but occasionally for no reason it gets enabled somehow, not sure how this happens, seems to be random and not related to a Windows Update or Software install.

Is there any way to disable it permanently in the registry system wide so this cannot happen again?

Will `gpedit` disable it permanently where it cannot be enabled easily? I prefer a registry edit if it is a more permanent solution.

```
Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Autoplay Policies\Turn off Autoplay
```

Did a clean install 2 weeks ago; my system is clean, I have no malware.

I'm using Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: Are you happy with a registry hack? http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-autorun-functionality-in-windows-using-registry-editor/

Comment: @TOG, Yes but is it confirmed to work for W7 by anyone, I saw some of these hacks for XP and it was reported to be a half fix. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I've not used them but the registry variable already exists in pro 64, so you should be able to try the values without problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group policy is going to be the most effective way to disable Autoplay.  It can't be overridden as long as the policy is in place.  Any registry-based setting would likely just be a registry-based policy setting, which has the same strength that 'normal' group policy does but is more difficult to administer.

I've never seen Group Policy do anything other than exactly what it says on the box.  If you configure it to say "never use Autorun" I would expect that to be true in all cases short of some pretty strange malware infections.

Comment: @ Bacon Bits, Thanks for the input, your user name is making me hungry!